# Requesting tiles without using XML file (GDAL C++)

Tags: gdal, c++

I have been able to request a specific tile with my XML through GDAL lib.

However, is there is another way of requesting the tiles from a web server without using XML?

I want to do it directly through my C++ code.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it through using any HTTP library. You first need to call `GetCapabilities` on the source URL:

```
http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/services/Specialty/ESRI_StatesCitiesRivers_USA/MapServer/WMSServer?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities&version=1.3.0
```

Which will give you a standard XML file (which will conform to a schema such as WMS) with information about layers, formats supported, and so on, which you'll need to parse. Then for the layers and areas you're interested in, you need to call `GetMap`:

```
http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/services/Specialty/ESRI_StatesCitiesRivers_USA/MapServer/WMSServer?VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&CRS=CRS:84&BBOX=-178.217598,18.924782,-66.969271,71.406235&WIDTH=765&HEIGHT=360&LAYERS=0,1,2&STYLES=,,Symbolizer&EXCEPTIONS=application/vnd.ogc.se_xml&FORMAT=image/png&BGCOLOR=0xFFFFFF&TRANSPARENT=TRUE
```

Which will give you the data in the format you requested as either a POST response, or possibly a download URL.

The details of how to do all this would best be asked on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 1):

You can provide XML data as string to the GDALOpenEx method:

```
const char *connStr = CPLSPrintf("<GDAL_WMS><Service name=\"TMS\">"
        "<ServerUrl>%s</ServerUrl></Service><DataWindow>"
        "<UpperLeftX>%f</UpperLeftX><UpperLeftY>%f</UpperLeftY>"
        "<LowerRightX>%f</LowerRightX><LowerRightY>%f</LowerRightY>"
        "<TileLevel>%d</TileLevel><TileCountX>1</TileCountX>"
        "<TileCountY>1</TileCountY><YOrigin>%s</YOrigin></DataWindow>"
        "<Projection>EPSG:%d</Projection><BlockSizeX>256</BlockSizeX>"
        "<BlockSizeY>256</BlockSizeY><BandsCount>%d</BandsCount>"
        "<Cache><Type>file</Type><Expires>%d</Expires><MaxSize>%d</MaxSize>"
        "</Cache><ZeroBlockHttpCodes>204,404</ZeroBlockHttpCodes></GDAL_WMS>",
                                     url.c_str(), extent.minX(),
                                     extent.maxY(), extent.maxX(),
                                     extent.minY(), z_max,
                                     y_origin_top ? "top" : "bottom",
                                     epsg, bandCount, cacheExpires,
                                     cacheMaxSize);

GDALDataset *pDS = static_cast<GDALDataset*>(GDALOpenEx( 
                          connStr, openFlags, nullptr, openOptions, nullptr));
```

By the way in this example also new GDAL feature - cache size limits and expired period.

Details can be found here: http://gdal.org/frmt_wms.html